# SVG to PDF using Apache FOP

Tags: java, pdf, svg, apache-fop

I have 3 SVG Files that I want to convert into a single PDF.
I'm trying to do this with Apache FOP, but i am thus far unsuccessful.

My idea was to simply write all 3 SVG files one after another into the resulting PDF, but that didn't work. My code for that looks like this:

```
public void convertSVG2PDF(File svg, File svg2, File svg3, File pdf) throws IOException,
        TranscoderException {

    // Create transcoder
    Transcoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();
    // Transcoder transcoder = new org.apache.fop.render.ps.PSTranscoder();

    // Setup input
    InputStream in = new java.io.FileInputStream(svg);
    InputStream in2 = new java.io.FileInputStream(svg2);
    InputStream in3 = new java.io.FileInputStream(svg3);

    try {
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(in);
        TranscoderInput input2 = new TranscoderInput(in2);
        TranscoderInput input3 = new TranscoderInput(in3);

        // Setup output
        OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdf);
        out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);
        try {
            TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(out);
            TranscoderOutput output2 = new TranscoderOutput(out);
            TranscoderOutput output3 = new TranscoderOutput(out);

            // Do the transformation
            transcoder.transcode(input, output);
            transcoder.transcode(input2, output2);
            transcoder.transcode(input3, output3);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

And lastly my SVG images look like this, they are generated from a  javascript application.

```
< svg height="70" id="topBar" version="1.1" width="1060" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip)" height="560" transform="translate(60,0)" width="1060">
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <rect height="70" width="1000"/>
  </clipPath>
  <rect fill="white" fill-opacity="1" height="70" id="rect" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" width="1000" x="0" y="0"/>
  <path d="M-35.63129521110456,34L-1.6312952111045584,68L32.36870478889544,34L-1.6312952111045584,1Z" fill="white" id="mileStones" stroke="green" stroke-width="2"/>
  <path d="M269.4286615414018,34L303.4286615414018,68L337.4286615414018,34L303.4286615414018,1Z" fill="white" id="mileStones" stroke="green" stroke-width="2"/>
  <path d="M674.5082762455497,34L708.5082762455497,68L742.5082762455497,34L708.5082762455497,1Z" fill="white" id="mileStones" stroke="green" stroke-width="2"/>
  <text id="mileStoneText" style="font-size: 15px;" x="-16.631295211104558" y="40">MS1</text>
  <text id="mileStoneText" style="font-size: 15px;" x="288.4286615414018" y="40">MS2</text>
  <text id="mileStoneText" style="font-size: 15px;" x="693.5082762455497" y="40">MS3</text>
</g>
```

My code thus far overwrites the pdf 2 times and the resulting PDF only contains the last SVG. I can also create 3 separate PDFs with the images inside. But i need all 3 on one page one beneath the other.

Comment: You may also embed all three SVGs in an HTML file and print that as PDF. This is possible as Chromium can run without a UI on a server.

Comment: I tried that, but then i get Root element namespace does not match that requested:
Requested: http://www.w3.org/2000/svg

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PDFMergerUtility](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFMergerUtility.html) to merge your PDFs. Here is some example code based on your code:

```
public class SvgToPdfConverter {

    private ArrayList<byte[]> pdfs = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    public void convertSVG2PDF(File svg) throws IOException, TranscoderException {
        // Create transcoder
        Transcoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();
        // Input
        FileInputStream bais = new FileInputStream(svg);
        // Output
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(bais);
        TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(baos);
        // Do the transformation
        transcoder.transcode(input, output);
        pdfs.add(baos.toByteArray());
    }

    public void merge(File mergedPDF) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
        PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
        for (byte[] bytes : pdfs) {
            ut.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        }
        ut.setDestinationStream(new FileOutputStream(mergedPDF));
        ut.mergeDocuments();
    }
}
```

And an example of a main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File exampleSVGFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "example.svg");
        File exampleOutputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "example.pdf");
        SvgToPdfConverter converter = new SvgToPdfConverter();
        try {
            converter.convertSVG2PDF(exampleSVGFile);
            converter.convertSVG2PDF(exampleSVGFile);
            converter.convertSVG2PDF(exampleSVGFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Converting svg failed. ", e);
        }
        try {
            converter.merge(exampleOutputFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Merge failed. ", e);
        }
    }
```